# Ruby static initialization inheritance

Tags: ruby, class, inheritance, static

I have a class in Ruby with some static initialization like this:

```
class Repository
  def self.my_static_setup
    ....
  end

  my_static_setup

  ...
end
```

The code above works fine, and my custom static initializer gets called, the problem is whenever I inherit this class:

```
class PersonRepository
  ...
end
```

The static initialization is not inherited, and therefore not called. What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

@megar told correctly, why the issue you are having.

As per OP's comment:

> I see it is not inherited, so I am trying to find a workaround to get self.my_static_setup called whenever I define subclasses.

I can then give you the below soltuion to things get work for you. See [`Class#inherited`](http://www.ruby-doc.org/core-2.1.0/Class.html#method-i-inherited) for the same, which is saying *Callback invoked whenever a subclass of the current class is created.*

```
class Repository
  def self.my_static_setup
    puts 'Hello!'
  end
  def self.inherited(subclass)
    my_static_setup
  end
end


class PersonRepository < Repository
  #...
end

# >> Hello!
```

Answer (score 0):

You're immediately invoking the method with `my_static_setup`. That part cannot be inherited, it's just code.

Comment: I see it is not inherited, so I am trying to find a workaround to get self.my_static_setup called whenever I define subclasses. I cannot find some type of self.class_initialize so I am not sure if the language support that